# Installing PyDev onto Eclipse issue

Tags: java, eclipse, pydev

So I am trying to get PyDev working on my eclipse. I am running eclipse version 4.5.2. I am trying to install PyDev version 5.1.2.

I have looked all over multiple forums just like this and I have tried doing everything that people have been saying to try. The problem I am encountering, is that when I install PyDev, it seems to work, but then I can't find it anywhere in preferences, meaning I cant use PyDev. It still says it is installed, under the installed category of the eclipse market place.

I think the problem has something to do with what version of java running. In my java installed JREs it says I have both java 8 jdk and jre7. The default is set to jdk8. I understand that the version of java I need to run this version of pydev is java 8, so I should be fine with that. But then I have seen others post to go to help>about>installation details> configuration. And then when I do that it says:

-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin\server\jvm.dll

which I assume to mean that it is using jre7.... which I dont understand how. I feel like this is the main problem with what I am experiencing, but I dont know for sure, and if it is the problem, I dont know how to fix it. Thank you in advance for the help.

When I edited the eclipse.ini file, this is what it looks like:

--launcher.library

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502

-showsplash

org.eclipse.platform

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize

256m

--launcher.defaultAction

openFile

-startup

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar

-vm

C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext

-vmargs

-Xms256m

-Xmx512m

-XX:MaxPermSize=256m

-XX:PermSize=64m

Answer (score 0):

The Installed JREs entries show you the JREs that Eclipse will use to run programs. It does not tell you the JRE that is used to run Eclipse itself.

Eclipse itself uses the default Java on your system unless you specify otherwise in the `eclipse.ini` file in your Eclipse install directory.

In the `eclipse.ini` specify:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre8/bin
```

(or whatever the path to your Java 8 is).

This entry must be on two lines are shown and it must be before an `-vmargs` line in the file.

Comment: I think I did what you are telling me to do. My eclipse.ini file is in the edited question now. So i did that and then i restarted eclipse, and still in the configuration, it has vm set to the java7 jre. And there is no pydev. Is there something else wrong or did I just not do this right?

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext` doesn't look like the correct directory. You must specify the one containing the java.exe or jvm.dll. I don't run Windows so I don't know what that is.

Comment: I changed it to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\bin     after trying C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin didnt work. Both ended up not working. All I have to do is save the file and then restart eclipse right? Or is there more to it?

Comment: That should be all you need to do to switch the Java used. I can't say if that will fix the pydev problem.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be changing the version of java it is using. Will it change the configuration file? Or is that just a permanent file, and the version of java has already changed?

Comment: By the way, thank you for the helpful responses, I appreciate it